# WinUI Mapsui Why setting zoom resets map centering?

Tags: c#, .net, openstreetmap, winui-3, mapsui

I've got a question about zooming and centering using [Mapsui](https://github.com/Mapsui/Mapsui) on a WinUI project.

Why does the map reset its centering when I perform ZoomToLevel?
This is my code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyMapControl.Map.Layers.Add(OpenStreetMap.CreateTileLayer());

    Debug.WriteLine($"There are {MyMapControl.Map.Layers[0].Resolutions.Count} zoom levels available");

    // Center map on 10.33333, 44.4444444
    CenterMapOnPosition(MyMapControl.Map, 10.33333, 44.4444444);

    ZoomMapToLevel(MyMapControl.Map, 5);

}

private void CenterMapOnPosition(Map map, double lon, double lat)
{

    // Get coordinates in spherical mercator
    MPoint sphericalMercatorPoint = SphericalMercator.FromLonLat(lon, lat).ToMPoint();

    // Center map on coordinates
    map.Home = n => n.CenterOn(sphericalMercatorPoint);

}

private void ZoomMapToLevel(Map map, int level)
{

    // Zoom map at specified level
    map.Home = n => n.ZoomToLevel(level);

}
```

When I call CenterMapOnPosition() the map is centered correctly. But when I call ZoomMapToLevel(), then map centering goes back to somewhere near africa.

I know I can do
`MyMap.Map.Home = n => n.CenterOnAndZoomTo(mercator, MyMap.Map.Layers[0].Resolutions[18]);`
but I need to have the two actions separated.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm expecting the map to remain centered on the specified position when I call ZoomMapToLevel(). I tried to use n.ZoomTo() instead of n.ZoomToLevel() but same problem.
Seems like zooming resets the map position at it's standard center, but with correct zoom.